# how close current git repository in terminal in vs code while working on other project

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I connected vs code to Git.

But when I work on other projects not in Git, in a terminal of vs code that git folder is running so if use terminal for other projects, changes are done on that Git folder.

For now, I disable Git in VSCode.

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I work on other projects not in git, in a terminal of vs code that git folder is running so if use terminal for other projects, changes are done on that git folder.

These changes should *not* be done in that Git folder.

Unless the other projects are in subfolders *below* the Git repository root folder.

If you make sure to use other projects in folders which are *not* subfolders of an existing Git repository, then no Git change will be recorded, and you can keep using VSCode for those other projects without influencing your existing Git repository.

Comment: Also if files that changes by other projects are not important for this project, you should add this files to `.gitignore`.

Comment: @LeszekMazur True, but I would prefer having two completely separate tree structures. Easier to manage that way.